# looping list of lists

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through 2 lists and then join them. But I am having trouble structuring the loop code.

It's Softimage (Animation 3D program) code, but I hope it makes sense.

This is what I have:

```
import os
import glob
app = Application
storeSelect=[]
mypath = app.ActiveProject.ActiveScene.filename.value
folder=[]
storeAll=[]
listObj=[]
path=[]
storeSelecte=[]
folderAll=[]
#Seleccion
app.SelectObj("*.geometry_cache_grp*")
mySelection = app.Selection


# GETS PATHS FOr each Character Folder

userPath=Application.XSIInputBox ("Direccion de Cache", "Cache")+ "/" 
os.chdir(userPath)


#/loops

for lis in mySelection:
    storeSelect.append(lis)
    members = app.SelectMembers(lis)
    app.SelectObj("*.geometry_cache_grp*")
    mySelection = app.Selection

    for files in sorted(glob.glob("*.scn_c*")):
        folder=files
        for lise in members:
            print lise,folder
```

But I am getting the result twice, like this:

```
# DI_CACHE.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
# DI_CACHE.vidrios Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
# DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
# DI_CACHE.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
# DI_CACHE.vidrios Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
# DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01 Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01 Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
```

Does anyone know how to correct my loop, so it only goes through it one time (only)? The result should look like this:

```
# DI_CACHE.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
# DI_CACHE.vidrios Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
# DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig 
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01 Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
# TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
```

Comment: You aren't getting the TOTO stuff at all?

Comment: You would better show these two original list.

Comment: It looks like you're reusing the same variable name for both loops, is that intentional? Can you try fixing that that to see if the result is different.

Comment: Hey it seems to me that the value of the lists are not what you expected, just print out the values of the lists before going to the for loop and show us what is in those two lists?

Comment: I CHANGE THE QUESTION ..

Comment: @user2250175 TYPING IN CAPS DOES NOT HELP.

Comment: It seems you're getting the cross-product of `app.SelectMembers(lis)` and `sorted(glob.glob("*.scn_c*")`, which appear to be completely independent of one another. I'm not sure what exactly you want, but perhaps you need to change one of those expressions, so that it is dependent on the value that was used to generate the other? Your `glob` call, for instance, might search for only the files with the right name in them (e.g. `DI` or `TOTO_GALLO`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it helps you but you can do something like:

```
members=[["DI_CACHE.lengua","DI_CACHE.vidrios","DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo"],["TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua","TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01","TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes"]]'
```

and

```
folders=[["Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig"],["Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig"]]
```

then

```
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    for n,m in itertools.product(a[i],b[i]):
        print n,m
```

result:

```
DI_CACHE.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
DI_CACHE.vidrios Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01 Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
```

Comment: @user2250175 : How come this answer is selected, yet it is posted as question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928701/looping-two-lists-of-lists)?