# looping two lists of lists

Tags: python

I need to loop through this lists but I am getting some confusion to make it.

This is my code:

```
folders=[["Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig"],["Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig"]]
members = members=[["DI_CACHE.lengua","DI_CACHE.vidrios","DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo"],["TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua","TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01","TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes"]]
```

.. and this is the desired result:

```
DI_CACHE.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
DI_CACHE.vidrios Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01 Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
```

How can I do that?  I tried several ways looping and looping and it didnt work.

Comment: -1: This question was accepted as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915146/looping-list-of-lists/15920005#15920005)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
folders = [["Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig"],["Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig"]]
members = [["DI_CACHE.lengua","DI_CACHE.vidrios","DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo"],["TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua","TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01","TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes"]]
print('\n'.join([
    '{m} {f}'.format(m=member, f=folder)
    for memberlist, folderlist in zip(members, folders)
    for member in memberlist
    for folder in folderlist]))
```

yields

```
DI_CACHE.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
DI_CACHE.vidrios Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01 Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
```

---

The list comprehension is equivalent to

```
result = []
for memberlist, folderlist in zip(members, folders):
    for member in memberlist:
        for folder in folderlist:
            result.append('{m} {f}'.format(m=member, f=folder))
```

The items in the list can then be printed (one on each line) with

```
 print('\n'.join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1. merge your lists
2. produce the product of the two lists

Use `itertools.product` for the latter, `zip` for the former.

```
from itertools import product

for fs, ms in zip(folders, members):
    for folder, member in product(fs, ms):
        print ' '.join((member, folder))
```

which produces:

```
>>> for fs, ms in zip(folders, members):
...     for folder, member in product(fs, ms):
...         print ' '.join((member, folder))
... 
DI_CACHE.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
DI_CACHE.vidrios Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01 Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig
```

The loop can be collapsed into a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import product

combinations = [(member, folder) for fs, ms in zip(folders, members) for folder, member in product(fs, ms)]
```

to produce a list:

```
>>> [(member, folder) for fs, ms in zip(folders, members) for folder, member in product(fs, ms)]
[('DI_CACHE.lengua', 'Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig'), ('DI_CACHE.vidrios', 'Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig'), ('DI_CACHE.dientes_abajo', 'Anim_2p.scn_c_DI_rig'), ('TOTO_GALLO_cache.lengua', 'Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig'), ('TOTO_GALLO_cache.dientes_01', 'Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig'), ('TOTO_GALLO_cache.plumas_guantes', 'Anim_2p.scn_c_TOTO_GALLO_rig')]
```

Comment: It looks like he wants to get the product of the items in the corresponding lists, not the product of the two lists were they flattened.  That is, `zip(folders, members)` will do half of the work.

Comment: @cdhowie: Ah, yes, I see how they are combined now.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is easy to solve if you loop on list indices instead of list items. For example, you could do something like:

```
for i in range(len(folders)):
    for m in members[i]:
        print(m, folders[i][0])
```